# I have problems installing the pysch package in R

Tags: r

I am starting to use R and I wanted to install the "pysch" package but for some reason I keep getting this error, I have the latest version of R, does anyone know what happened with this package?

Warning in install.packages :
package ‘pysch’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages

Comment: What version of R are you running? What does `options("repos")` return for you? What command did you run exactly to get that message?

Comment: Version: 4.1.0 (2021-05-18)
command: install.packages("pysch")
I don't know what you mean by "options("repos")",i'm new to all this

Comment: In think you’ve just spelled the name of the package wrong. I think you want “psych” not “pysch”